# Retrieve id of an ImageView when on Drag and Drop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have 3 containers, one contains several `ImageViews` that the user can drag and drop to the 2 other containers. For that I need to identify which `ImageView` has been dropped. I thought that `getId()` was doing it but it retrieves the Id of the target container which makes sense.

In the code I'm using `img_select` to try to store the value of the id the `ImageView` moved. Any example of how to do it?

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                img_select = v.getId();
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackground(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // I tried to do it here. I get the id of the container
                img_select = v.getId();
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                owner.removeView(view);
                RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try with android:tag? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:tag

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are storing the id of the view parent and not the view being dragged. Try using the id from:

`View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
img_select = view.getId()`

Don't forget to change it in ACTION_DRAG_STARTED as well.

Comment: I'm getting -1 as areult